# SSH connection impossible when login locally and vice versa

Tags: ssh, login, 23.04

I set up a shared workstation (Ubuntu 23.04) at my office, my colleagues and I mainly access it through SSH connection, but, if I login locally to the machine, other users cannot access it through SSH. The same problem presents in the opposite direction, so, if a user is logged in through SSH, I cannot access to the desktop session locally (the behaviour is that it does not respond to any input and I am not able to do the login).

So the question is: is this even possible?
In the case it is possible, how can I enable this?

Thank you for the answers!

Comment: Are you saying you already set this up somehow and want to know how it can be done again?

Comment: @muru no, it is not set up, I was wondering how to set it up.

Comment: So what do you mean by "the ... problem presents"?

Comment: Can multiple SSH users be logged in simultaneously?